# Zend Framework Controller File (Apple Icons)

Tags: zend-framework, header

Question about including some header information in controller file in zend framework.  I am wanting to include the apple icons.  Going off of this here: http://gigaom.com/apple/how-to-create-ios-device-home-screen-icons-for-web-sites/

However the 'sizes' block is not showing up when I look at the actual source of page that this is on.  I'm assuming rel and href are native to zend framework already.  How do I get the 'sizes' to show up?

```
$this->view->headLink(array('rel' => 'apple-touch-icon', 'href' => '/images/icons/apple-touch-icon.png'));
    $this->view->headLink(array('rel' => 'apple-touch-icon', 'sizes' => '72x72', 'href' => '/images/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png'));
    $this->view->headLink(array('rel' => 'apple-touch-icon', 'sizes' => '114x114', 'href' => '/images/icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png'));
```

This is what is actually showed upon viewing source of page in header.

```
<link href="/images/icons/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<link href="/images/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<link href="/images/icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sizes` and any other attributes not supported out-of-the-box by `headLink()` should go in an `extras` array, like so:

```
$this->view->headLink(array('rel' => 'apple-touch-icon', 
    'href' => '/images/icons/apple-touch-icon.png'));

$this->view->headLink(array('rel' => 'apple-touch-icon', 
    'href' => '/images/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png', 
    'extras' => array('sizes' => '72x72')));

$this->view->headLink(array('rel' => 'apple-touch-icon', 
    'href' => '/images/icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png', 
    'extras' => array('sizes' => '114x114')));
```

(Lines wrapped for clarity.)