# Zend Framework 2: adding custom attribute in favicon icon

Tags: css, zend-framework, zend-framework2

My front end designer give html where favicon icon showing code like following.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="ico/favicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="ico/favicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="ico/favicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="ico/favicon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/favicon.png">
```

I am in stuck how to show sizes attribute. i am trying like following.

```
$this->headLink(
        array('rel' => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',   'href' => $this->basePath() . '/admin_assets/img/favicon.ico',array('sizes' => '144x144'))
```

But sizes is not showing in output. Anybody have idea how to show custom attribute in favicon. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11655485

Use the 'extras' array key for non-standard attributes like so:

```
$this->headLink(
    array(
        'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
        'href' => $this->basePath() . '/admin_assets/img/favicon.ico',
        'extras' => array('sizes' => '144x144')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`HeadLink` helper class strictly defines the list of valid attributes

```
protected $itemKeys = array('charset', 'href', 'hreflang', 'id', 'media', 'rel', 'rev', 'type', 'title', 'extras');
```

and rejects everything else. [See the line on github.](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/HeadLink.php#L38)
So it seems that `sizes` is invalid attribute for helper.

First of all, if you can use plain html to output these `link` tags, just use it.
Otherwise, I've came up with the following solution:

1) Create your own `CustomHeadLink` class that extends original `HeadLink`, and extend the array that defines a list of valid attributes:

```
<?php

namespace Custom\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\HeadLink;

class CustomHeadLink extends HeadLink
{
    // added 'sizes' as a new attribute
    protected $itemKeys = array('charset', 'href', 'hreflang', 'id', 'media', 'rel', 'rev', 'type', 'title', 'extras', 'sizes');
}
```

2) Make your module use your custom helper instead of Zend's one:

```
<?php

namespace Custom;

// ...
use Custom\View\Helper\CustomHeadLink;
// ...

class Module
{
    // ...
    public function getViewHelperConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'headLink' => function($serviceManager) {
                    return new CustomHeadLink();
                },
            ),
        );
    }
    // ...
}
```

As a result you can still access helper from layout with no changes, but with new attribute support:

```
$this->headLink(array(
    'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
    'href' => $this->basePath() . '/admin_assets/img/favicon.ico',
    'sizes' => '144x144'
));
```